# Using struct with Objective-C methods

Tags: objective-c, data-structures, objective-c++

I'm writing a simple game, and thought it would be much easier to use structures. However, I can't declare methods that need the structs.

How could I use a struct as an argument to an Objective-C method and get an object of the struct returned?

```
//my structure in the .h file
struct Entity
{
  int entityX;
  int entityY;
  int entityLength;
  int entityWidth;
  int entityType;
  bool isDead;
};

//And the methods i'm trying to use
-(BOOL)detectCollisionBetweenEntity:Entity ent1 andEntity:Entity ent2;

-(struct Entity)createEntityWithX:int newEntityX andY:int newEntityY, withType:int newEntityType withWidth:int newEntityWidth andLength:int newEntityLength;
```

Comment: If you're going to use C data structures I suggest you familiarise yourself with how you manage memory in C, and how pointers work. This topic is far too big to cover in a SO question & answer. Your other option is to stick with Objective-C, this might be less confusing to start off with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use structs exactly like you would expect, your problem seems to be with the syntax of methods:

```
struct Entity
{
  int entityX;
  int entityY;
  int entityLength;
  int entityWidth;
  int entityType;
  bool isDead;
};

//And the methods i'm trying to use
-(BOOL)detectCollisionBetweenEntity:(struct Entity) ent1 andEntity:(struct Entity) ent2;

-(struct Entity)createEntityWithX:(int) newEntityX andY:(int) newEntityY withType:(int) newEntityType withWidth:(int) newEntityWidth andLength:(int) newEntityLength;
```

Types in methods need to be in parens, and you have to refer to `struct Entity` instead of `Entity` unless you typedef (in plain Objective-C, Objective-C++ might let you do it)

Answer (score 2):

Structs are used as parameters in Objective-C all the time. For example the CGRect from Apple's [CGGeometry Reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cggeometry?language=objc)

```
struct CGRect {
  CGPoint origin;
  CGSize size; 
}; 
typedef struct CGRect CGRect;
```

You just have to create a type for your struct, which can be done in the same way as Apple, or could have been done as

```
typedef struct CGRect {
  CGPoint origin;
  CGSize size; 
} CGRect;
```

So in your case:

```
typedef struct
{
  int entityX;
  int entityY;
  int entityLength;
  int entityWidth;
  int entityType;
  bool isDead;
} Entity;
```

Should allow you to define

```
-(BOOL)detectCollisionBetweenEntity:(Entity) ent1 andEntity:(Entity) ent2;
-(Entity)createEntityWithX:int newEntityX andY:int newEntityY, withType:int newEntityType withWidth:int newEntityWidth andLength:int newEntityLength;
```